# ASP.NET Cookie not set when using https

Tags: asp.net, cookies, https

I have an ASP.NET application which stores a "Remember Me" token as a cookie; it worked fine until I implemented SSL.

Using FireCookies, I never see my cookie (named "_rmtoken") though ".ASPXAUTH", "ASP.NET_SessionId" and other cookies do show up.  Here is the code I use to set the cookie:

```
public static void SetRememberMeCookie(HttpContext context, Guid token)
{
    DeleteRememberMeCookie(context);
    var loginCookie = new HttpCookie("_rmtoken")
    {
        Value = token.ToString(),
        Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1), 
        HttpOnly=false, 
        Secure = false
    };
    context.Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line from false to true

```
Secure = false
```

[Msdn Reference - HttpCookie.Secure property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure.aspx)

Comment: per the code, Secure is already set to false.  It doesn't work.

Comment: sorry wasn't completely clear, change the line from Secure=false to Secure=true

Comment: Why doesn't the cookie get set when it's false? What if we don't want the cookie flagged as secure?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to set cookie's domain property for your cookies:

```
Response.Cookies["your_cookie_name"].Domain = "yourdomain.com";
```

... or check out [this article](http://4rapiddev.com/csharp/asp-net-cookie-domains-http-https/) to get more information.